# Fn Key on T61 (8889-2bg not working at all

Tags: windows-7, fn-key

I installed Windows 7 Professional on a Lenovo T61 (8889-2BG), and now the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key does not work at all.

The driver for the Synaptics touchpad and all the other Thinkvantage and Lenovo drivers are installed.

In addition, advanced touchpad functions do not work either.

Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> provides some functions, but the LEDs on the keyboard do not work.

Could this be a hardware bug? In the Hardware Manager, I see *Standard PS/2 driver for keyboard* and it is not possible to get another driver for the keyboard on the T60.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The FN keys' functions are not provided provided by the any drivers but the thinkpad hot key utility. Also Fn + Fx functions will work in some basic form even if you don't have the utility installed. So your Fn key is either damanged or you haved used the customize keyboard utility to remap it. Any easy way to test if it is working is to check if pressing the Fn key wakes your computer up from sleep mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have a T61 and there were several issues with drivers.  I downloaded the [ThinkVantage System update](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=TVSU-UPDATE) and it grabbed all needed drivers easily.  Not sure if that is the ThinkVantage drivers you refer to in your post. Solved a couple of issues for me.

Comment: The Fn test to wakeup the system seems to prove the the Fn key is malfunctioning.